# How to download upstream branches?

Tags: git, github, branch, fork

I forked a repo on GitHub with many branches. All the branches show up on GitHub. I do this to download the repo:

```
git clone git-repo-url
cd git-repo
git remote add upstream git-upstream-url
git fetch upstream
```

This all works fine, but when I try to `checkout` a branch, it doesn't work. I only have the master branch. What do I need to do to download the other branches?

Comment: What does it show if you run `git branch -r`?

Comment: @Cameron - The branches DO show up, they just aren't accessible.

Comment: OK, if they're showing up then @Manojlds' answer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the remote branches also by doing:

```
git branch -a
```

To checkout a branch, try:

```
git checkout -b local-branch upstream/branch
```